# angularjs how to use service $scope variable in another function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

In my angularjs html file, i am reading a file data using a service and showing data in directive. It is working fine in displaying treeview. I have put a ng-click "ShowDetailsFunc()" for each item and want to get details from the variable ($scope.testdata). The problem is the data which i am getting from service is not accessible from ng-click function and shows as "undefined". i understand that $scope.testdata takes some time to get value as it comes from $http service but i am also trying to get once it is fully loaded. As far i understand once $scope variable is set, should be accessible in entire controller function and can be accessed anywhere.

I thought of using $watch but I think it is used for watching a normal variable. please help if my understand is not right or i am making some mistake somewhere.

My directive as below,

```
mainApp.directive('collection', function () {       
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {collection: '='},       
        template: "<ul><member ng-repeat='member in collection' member='member'></member></ul>"         
    }
})

mainApp.directive('member', function ($compile) {
    var NewChild = "<li><span ng-click=ShowDetailsFunc()>{{member.NodeName}}</span></li>";      
    var linkerfunc = function(scope, element, attrs) {  
                    var collectionSt = '<collection collection="member.children"></collection>';
                    $compile(collectionSt)(scope, function(cloned, scope)   {                                           
                        element.append(cloned); 
                     });
                    scope.ShowDetailsFunc = function() {                        
                        scope.ShowDetailsCtrlFunc(element,event);                     
                    } 

    }
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {member: '=', ShowDetailsCtrlFunc : '&'},
        template: NewChild,     
        controller: 'TreeController',
        link: linkerfunc        
    }
})
```

And my controller function,

```
mainApp.controller('TreeController', function ($scope,$http,getTestDataService,$timeout) {      
    $scope.Intialfunc = function() { 
        $scope.testdata = []
        var filename = 'D:\\myxmlfile.xml'      
            getTestDataService.gettestdata(filename).then(function success(response){
                $(response.data.children).each(function(index,value){
                $scope.testdata.push(value);            
                })
            console.log($scope.testdata) // showing data here.
            });         
        }   
    $scope.ShowDetailsCtrlFunc = function(element,event) {
            console.log("in function ShowDetailsCtrlFunc"); // coming to this fucntion on click.        
            console.log($scope.testdata) // but this one is not showing . shows undefined.
            .....................................
            some other code using $scope.testdata
            .....................................

            event.stopImmediatePropagation();           
      };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By default angular would not bind `this` of directive to the controller, to achieve this you should use `bindToController` property in return statement of directive. For more details check [this](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/02/exploring-angular-1.3-bindToController.html)

Comment: I read the blog but couldn't get an idea how to use bindToController with directive function. could you please explain.